# Kivy: returning value for use in other functions

Tags: python, kivy

My python file:

class MainScreen(Screen):
    ampm = ObjectProperty(None)
    weekend = ObjectProperty(None)

```
def switch_ampm_clicked(self, instance, value):
    print ("ampm args = " + str(value))
    if value is True:
        ampm = "PM"
        print (ampm)
        return ampm
    else:
        ampm = "AM"
        print (ampm)
        return ampm

def switch_weekend_clicked(self, instance, value):
    print ("weekend args = " + str(value))
    if value is True:
        weekend = "Weekend"
        print (weekend)
        return weekend
    else:
        weekend = "Weekday"
        print (weekend)
        return weekend

def add_alarm(self):
    alarm_to_enter = str(self.hour.text + ":" + self.minute.text + ":" + self.second.text + " " + str(self.ampm) + " " + str(self.weekend))
    self.db_conn = lite.connect('ust_bac.db')
    self.theCursor = self.db_conn.cursor
    # Insert alarms in the db
    #self.db_conn.execute('INSERT INTO Alarms (Hour, Minute, Second, AM_PM, Weekend) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (self.hour.text, self.minute.text, self.second.text, self.checkbox_ampm_clicked(), self.checkbox_weekend_clicked.weekend))
    print (alarm_to_enter)
```

My kv file:

:
    name: 'main_screen'
    on_enter: root.starttimer()
    hour: hour
    minute: minute
    second: second
    weekend: week_end
    ampm: am_pm
    alarm_list: alarm_list

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (1, 1)

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1, .833)
        #width: 800
        #height: 400

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: (.5, 1)

            LabelB:
                text: "Alarm Times"
                size_hint: (1, .1)
                bcolor: 0,0,1,1

            ListView:
                id: alarm_list
                size_hint: (1, .6)
                adapter:
                    ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.AlarmListButton)

            BoxLayout:
                id: user_input_section
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: (1, .1)

                LabelB:
                    text: "Hour"
                    bcolor: 0,0,1,1
                TextInput:
                    id: hour
                LabelB:
                    text: "Minute"
                    bcolor: 0,0,1,1
                TextInput:
                    id: minute
                LabelB:
                    text: "Second"
                    bcolor: 0,0,1,1
                TextInput:
                    id: second

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: (1, .1)

                LabelB:
                    text:
                    size_hint: (.25, 1)
                    bcolor: 0,0,1,1
                Switch:
                    id: am_pm
                    on_active: root.switch_ampm_clicked(self, self.active)
                    size_hint: (.25, 1)
                LabelB:
                    text:
                    size_hint: (.25, 1)
                    bcolor: 0,0,1,1
                Switch:
                    id: week_end
                    on_active: root.switch_weekend_clicked(self, self.active)
                    size_hint: (.25, 1)
```

My results:

```
07:00:00 <kivy.uix.switch.Switch object at 0x0A1AAE68> <kivy.uix.switch.Switch object at 0x0A1B47A0>
```

I can not figure out how to get the value of ampm or weekend so I can store it in my db.

I have followed the answer in [Kivy : read switch state in others python functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865349/kivy-read-switch-state-in-others-python-functions), but I get the same exact result.

I have included just portions of my code.

Comment: What? You can [edit] your question you know.

Comment: There are currently no edits on this question.

Comment: I have figure out how to edit the original question, and get it to show right, and deleted my comments. Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow, and didn't realize I had to format it as code to get it to display properly. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

1. ***ampm*** and ***weekend*** defined as ***ObjectProperty*** but you are assigning string to them
2. In the methods (switch_ampm_clicked, switch_weekend_clicked), ***ampm*** and ***weekend*** are defined as ***local variable***.

## Solution

1. ***ampm*** and ***weekend*** define as ***StringProperty***
2. In the methods (switch_ampm_clicked, switch_weekend_clicked), replaced ***ampm*** and ***weekend*** with ***self.ampm*** and ***self.weekend***.

## Snippets

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    ampm = StringProperty("")
    weekend = StringProperty("")

    def switch_ampm_clicked(self, switch, value):
        print("ampm args = " + str(value))
        if switch.active:   # if True
            self.ampm = "PM"
        else:
            self.ampm = "AM"
        print(self.ampm)

    def switch_weekend_clicked(self, switch, value):
        print("weekend args = " + str(value))
        if switch.active:
            self.weekend = "Weekend"
        else:
            self.weekend = "Weekday"
        print(self.weekend)
```